# setuid(0) fails to execute for root owned program

Tags: c, linux, shell, root, setuid

I need to write some code which can gain root priveleges and execute system level operations. Here's what I've written (this is not the actual code, just to test if I'm doing things correctly or not):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    int current_uid = getuid();
    printf("My UID is: %d. My GID is: %d\n", current_uid, getgid());
    system("/usr/bin/id");
    if (setuid(0))
    {
        perror("setuid");
        return 1;
    }
    //I am now root!
    printf("My UID is: %d. My GID is: %d\n", getuid(), getgid());
    system("/usr/bin/id");
    //Time to drop back to regular user privileges
    setuid(current_uid);
    printf("My UID is: %d. My GID is: %d\n", getuid(), getgid());
    system("/usr/bin/id");
    return 0;
}
```

After doing `gcc -o setuid setuid.c`, I run ls -al on this to get following results:

```
tarun@staging:~$ ls -al setuid
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tarun tarun 9792 2009-10-03 18:09 setuid
adam@staging:~$
```

Trying to run the application results in:

```
tarun@staging:~$ ./setuid
My UID is: 1000. My GID is: 1000
uid=1000(tarun) gid=1000(tarun) groups=1000(tarun),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),125(sambashare),999(bumblebee)
setuid: Operation not permitted
```

I change the owner to root and set the sticky bits accordingly:

```
tarun@staging:~$ su - root
Password:
staging:~# cd /home/tarun
staging:/home/tarun# chown root.root setuid
staging:/home/tarun# chmod +s setuid
staging:/home/tarun# ls -al setuid
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 9792 2009-10-03 18:09 setuid
staging:/home/tarun# exit
logout
tarun@staging:~$
```

Executing the program now gives:

```
adam@staging:~$ ./setuid
My UID is: 1000. My GID is: 1000
uid=1000(tarun) gid=1000(tarun) groups=1000(tarun),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),125(sambashare),999(bumblebee)
setuid: Operation not permitted
```

While ideally it should have executed fully and changed my `uid` to 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I find it odd that your file is from 2009, anyway, the steps you followed should work and, indeed, they've worked on my machine.

Comment: @Rafael I guess this must be a problem with my system then. Wil see if I can figure out what's wrong with this.

Comment: Check the output of mount to see if suid is enabled. Maybe the partition is mounted with nosuid.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out the filesystem I'm using is type `ecryptfs`, which enforces nosuid and nodev to avoid privilege escalation attacks. I don't think I can turn it off. Any way around this?

Comment: Added link which should help you tame eCryptFS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No problem with your code, just check correct `setuid` / 'sgid' sequence:

```
sudo chmod 6775 setuid
sudo chown root:root setuid
```

You must set at least SUID, SGID and execution permissions (6555 mask). Also it's common for this case to set user/group write (6775 mask). Of course for security you can limit this to user write mask (6755).

And please beassure you don't drop permissions during re-compile:

```
$ ls -al
-rwsrwsr-x 1 root  root  8772 Feb  8 17:52 setuid
```

Just in case you (or future readers) need such guide: 
[What is SUID and how to set SUID in Linux/Unix?](https://www.linuxnix.com/suid-set-suid-linuxunix/)

Regarding to issues with eCryptfs: here is article which should help you: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but it still doesn't work. `ls -al` yields the desired output, but `./setuid` still doesn't get me root permissions :-/

Comment: Please check both UID and SGID. You are not in group 0.

Answer (score 1):

The sticky bit has an entirely different function.  On a file it is largely undefined these days, while on a directory it prevents non-owners (other than root) from removing files in the directory regardless of the directory permissions.

You are looking for the set UID bit:

```
  chown root setuid
  chmod +s setuid
```

Obviously you must be root to set the SUID permission for a root owned file.  Since the setUID bit exists, though, I suspect that you may be going to effort that is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
chown root.root setuid
```

to

```
chown root setuid
```

or

```
chown root.tarun setuid
```

Comment: Note: some file systems require the setuid allowed option to be set when mounted.   In order to allow setuid operations. Check your mountpoint.